# Delete row properly in Master View

Tags: ios, uitableview, uisplitviewcontroller, master-detail

I have Split View. Master View is a table. When I delete selected row in Master View the Detail View still stays on screen and user can interact with it. How can I hide it until another row in Master View will be selected?

**Edit:**

I use the following code in master view controller to populate detail view controller's view:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{     
    [self.detailViewController loadData];    
}
```

Comment: You should show the code you use to populate your detail view controller's view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my Application I use an UILabel covering the whole detailview with the text "Select an item from List" until another row is selected.